# Child component Input () data is undefined when loaded

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a parent component and that needs to be loaded multiple child components. The child components are to be loaded by taking the object from parent, so far its working as expected. But the problem here is, I have a button to be rendered in the child component and the text of the button comes from parent component. If I click on that button the respective child component should open and the data which came from parent component should be shown in the child component, here whenever I click on child component button, the child component is getting opened but the `input()` data is getting undefined. Because of this the data from the parent component is not displaying in the child component when it is expanded. Here is the sample code **:**

parentcompoent.html **:**

```
<div *ngFor="let tile of tiles$ | async;">
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="$any(getSelectedComponentTemplete(tile.tileUrl))"
                    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: {data:tile} }">
</ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #card let-obj>
<app-child [data]="obj.data"></app-child>
</ng-template>`
```

parentcomponent.component.ts **:**

```
@ViewChild('card', { static: true }) card!: TemplateRef<any>;

getSelectedComponentTemplete(type: string) {
switch (type) {
case "card":
return this.card;
default:
return;
}
```

childcomponent.html **:**

```
<mat-card>
<mat-card-title>
<button [routerLink]="data?.cardUrl" [disableRipple]="true" mat-flat-button>{{data?.tileName}}</button>
</mat-card-title>
</mat-card>`
```

childcomponent.component.ts **:**

```
@Input()
data!: any;

ngOnInit(): void {
console.log(this.data);
}
```

I don't know why its loading perfectly when the child component is part of parent component and its not loading data when I click on the button in child component.

Can someone help me on this ?

Comment: You pass value to child as `<app-child [data]="obj.data"></app-child>` - is `obj.data` available in parent?

Comment: Yes, its there. 
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="$any(getSelectedComponentTemplete(tile.healthKeyUrl))"
                        [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: {data:tile} }">
    </ng-container>

Comment: This feels terribly un-Angular, but I may be wrong. Is there any reason you're not using "normal" component communication, via a service or @Input/@Output?

Comment: I don't know why you have felt like that, my requirement is to dynamically load the child component in parent component (basically not single child but in the example I have given the sample and singe component) based on some logic. And for your information I have used @input() to transfer data from parent to child you can clearly see in the above code. I have used Angular correctly as per my requirement, hopefully now you can read the question and follow the example clearly.